# O que é um elemento inerte?

Tags: html5

Eu fiz uma pergunta sobre [tabindex](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/194840/como-e-onde-funciona-o-tabindex) aqui no site e acabei esbarrando com o termo *elementos inertes*.

Percebi que é algo que está na [especificação da w3c](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#inert), e ainda por cima existe um [Polyfill para o atributo "inert"](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/inert-polyfill).

Sobre isso tenho algumas dúvidas:

- O que seria um elemento inerte?
- No HTML5, vai existir ou existe um atributo que marque um elemento como inerte?
- Se isso é uma novidade, o que poderá mudar com a implementação?

Answer (score 2):

É uma feature que está em desenvolvimento, mas de momento ainda não está activa em browsers existentes.

> The inert attribute is a draft feature of HTML. As of Feb 2017, no browser >has a native implementation of inert. However, there is active development >inside Chrome, and other browsers have shown some renewed interest.
>
> **From the HTML spec**-
>
> A node (in particular elements and text nodes) can be marked as inert. >When a node is inert, then the user agent must act as if the node was >absent for the purposes of targeting user interaction events, may ignore >the node for the purposes of text search user interfaces (commonly known >as "find in page"), and may prevent the user from selecting text in that >node.

É uma feature que permite disabilitar componentes, quer para focus/activação/selecção mas também impossibilitar pesquisa.

É um atributo que deverá ser opcional para todas as suas possíveis utilizações num futuro próximo caso entre em fase de produção.

Já existe quem esteja a preparar componentes e scripts para a inclusão do Inert, tentando ultrapassar a limitação actual dos browsers não reconhecerem o atributo injectando via script.

Referências:

W3C Html 5.1 Inertness - https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/editing.html#inertness

Polyfill for the HTML inert attribute GitHub - https://github.com/GoogleChrome/inert-polyfill