# Como funciona a tag <dialog>? Ela tem futuro?

Tags: html5, modal, dialog, html-tags

Há algum tempo atrás, lendo alguns artigos sobre HTML5, fiquei sabendo da existência da tag [`<dialog>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog).

Eu fiquei curioso pra saber como ela funciona, pois atualmente quando se trata de diálogos (também conhecidos como "modais") são quase sempre feitos à mão ou com biblioteca de terceiros. Talvez fosse legal ter algo  padronizado quanto aos diálogos de um site.

Exemplo (só funciona no Chrome)

```js
(function() {
  var updateButton = document.getElementById('updateDetails');
  var cancelButton = document.getElementById('cancel');
  var favDialog = document.getElementById('favDialog');

  // Update button opens a modal dialog
  updateButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    favDialog.showModal();
  });

  // Form cancel button closes the dialog box
  cancelButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    favDialog.close();
  });
})();
```

```html
<!-- esse exemplo foi tirado da MDN e creio que só vai funcionar no Google Chrome -->
<dialog open id="favDialog">
  <form method="dialog">
    <section>
      <p><label for="favAnimal">Favorite animal:</label>
      <select id="favAnimal">
        <option></option>
        <option>Brine shrimp</option>
        <option>Red panda</option>
        <option>Spider monkey</option>
      </select></p>
    </section>
    <menu>
      <button id="cancel" type="reset">Cancel</button>
      <button type="submit">Confirm</button>
    </menu>
  </form>
</dialog>

<menu>
  <button id="updateDetails">Update details</button>
</menu>
```

Gostaria de saber:

- Qual é a finalidade e como funciona a tag `<dialog>`?
- Qual é a compatibilidade dessa tag?
- Essa tag tem futuro?

<sub>Creio que já tem um tempo que vi que essa tag existe, mas ainda até hoje (2017) parece-me que ela está assinalada como tendo suporte apenas no Google Chrome, além de parecer bastante impopular.</sub>

Comment: [Pra que serve a tag DataList](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/197571/pra-que-serve-a-tag-datalist)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

O elemento `<dialog>`, do HTML 5, junto com os elementos `<details>` e `<summary>`, está caracterizado, nas especificações da W3C e na WHATWG, como um elemento interativo, [W3C sessão 4.11.3](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/interactive-elements.html#the-dialog-element) e [WHATWG sessão 4.11.4](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interactive-elements.html#the-dialog-element).

No topo deste mesmo arquivo há o texto:

> *The following features are at risk and may be removed due to lack of implementation.*
>
> - `<dialog>`
> - `<details>` and `<summary>`

O que indica que o futuro destes elementos podem estar comprometidos. Não fica claro, nem nas especificações, nem nas documentações dos navegadores quais são os riscos que estes elementos causam e se esse é o real motivo para eles não terem desenvolvido suporte aos tais.

Ela surgiu no HTML 5 e tem uma palavra que resume toda esta versão: semântica. Como você bem descreveu na pergunta, hoje as janelas modais são criadas a partir de elementos que não foram elaborados para tal, que demandam de auxílio do JavaScript e CSS para possuírem o comportamento desejado. Recentemente tanto a W3C quanto a WHATWG começaram a justamente incriminar essas coisas, pois afeta a semântica do documento. Assim, definiram a tag `<dialog>` justamente para criar as janelas modais de forma nativa, apenas com HTML, usando JS apenas para controlar sua exibição, através dos eventos na página, geralmente.

Feita a introdução, vamos às perguntas:

> Qual é a finalidade e como funciona a tag `<dialog>`?

Como comentado, a tag `dialog>` foi especificada justamente com o intuito de permitir o uso de janelas modais de forma nativa, sem depender de bibliotecas para isso. Algo no meio do caminho parece que saiu errado e os navegadores não desenvolveram suporte a ela. Como funciona?

#### Como funciona?

O elemento `<dialog>` é um [elemento fluido](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/dom.html#flow-content-1) e suporta qualquer conteúdo fluido. Possui suporte a todos os [atributos globais](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#global-attributes) mais o atributo `open`, que define quando a janela de diálogo deve ser exibida.

Sua interface no DOM é:

```
[Exposed=Window,
 HTMLConstructor]
interface HTMLDialogElement : HTMLElement {
  [CEReactions] attribute boolean open;
  attribute DOMString returnValue;
  [CEReactions] void show();
  [CEReactions] void showModal();
  [CEReactions] void close(optional DOMString returnValue);
};
```

O atributo `open` é do tipo booleano e, quando especificado, indica que a janela de diálogo  está ativa e que o usuário pode interagir com ela. Quando omitido, a janela de diálogo não deverá ser exibida ao usuário.

> **Nota:** omitindo o atributo `open` *costuma* ocultar a janela de diálogo, porém, ao fazê-lo, atente-se às consequências:
>
> - O evento `close` não será disparado;
> - O método `close()`, junto com qualquer outro método de cancelamento provido pelo agente de usuário, não terá mais a competência de fechar
>     a janela;
> - Se a janela for exibida pelo método `showModal()`, o documento continuará [bloqueado](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#blocked-by-a-modal-dialog).
>
> Por estas razões, praticamente nunca será recomendado remover o
>   atributo `open` manualmente; prefira sempre fechar a janela através do
>   método `close()`.

<sup>Nota retirada e traduzida da especificação WHATWG.</sup>

O atributo [`tabindex`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/194840/5878) jamais deverá ser especificado para o elemento, pois, quando aberto, bloqueará o documento, sendo o único elemento a ser interagido (pois todos os elementos do documento passam a ficar [inertes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/194854/5878)) e, quando ocultado, não deverá fazer parte da navegação.

Sobre os métodos do elemento no DOM< temos:

- `dialog.show()`: Exibe a janela de diálogo;
- `dialog.showModal()`: exibe a janela de diálogo na forma modal, sobrepondo todo o conteúdo¹;
- `dialog.close([returnValue])`: oculta o elemento e, se possuir um argumento, terá seu valor retornado (este mesmo valor poderá ser definido através de `dialog.returnValue`);

¹: Quando utilizados mais de um `<dialog>` no documento, ao utilizar o método `show()` em todos, a ordem deles no documento importará, sendo o último sobrepondo todos os outros, já quando utilizado o método `showModal()`, sobreporá todo o documento aquela janela no qual foi aberta por último. Testes demonstrando este comportamento mais abaixo.

**Exemplo com duas janelas de diálogos abertas inicialmente**

> Só funciona no Google Chrome!

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora quae doloribus consequuntur unde, atque inventore numquam corporis vel, quod neque cupiditate optio fuga, natus beatae architecto blanditiis voluptate perspiciatis debitis.</p>

<input type="text">

<dialog open id="dialog1">
  <p>Janela de diálogo 1</p>
  <button onclick="this.parentElement.close()">Fechar</button>
</dialog>

<dialog open id="dialog2">
  <p>Janela de diálogo 2</p>
  <button onclick="this.parentElement.close()">Fechar</button>
</dialog>
```

**Exemplo com duas janelas de diálogo utilizando o método `show()`**

> Só funciona no Google Chrome!

```js
dialog1.close();
dialog2.close();

dialog2.show();
dialog1.show();
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora quae doloribus consequuntur unde, atque inventore numquam corporis vel, quod neque cupiditate optio fuga, natus beatae architecto blanditiis voluptate perspiciatis debitis.</p>

<input type="text">

<dialog open id="dialog1">
  <p>Janela de diálogo 1</p>
  <button onclick="this.parentElement.close()">Fechar</button>
</dialog>

<dialog open id="dialog2">
  <p>Janela de diálogo 2</p>
  <button onclick="this.parentElement.close()">Fechar</button>
</dialog>
```

Perceba que, mesmo que `dialog1.show()` foi chamado depois de `dialog2.show()`, a janela 2 se sobreporá a 1 devido a ordem que estão expostas no documento.

**Exemplo com duas janelas de diálogo utilizando o método `showModal()`**

> Só funciona no Google Chrome!

```js
const dialog1 = document.getElementById("dialog1");
const dialog2 = document.getElementById("dialog2");

dialog1.close();
dialog2.close();

dialog2.showModal();
dialog1.showModal();
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora quae doloribus consequuntur unde, atque inventore numquam corporis vel, quod neque cupiditate optio fuga, natus beatae architecto blanditiis voluptate perspiciatis debitis.</p>

<input type="text">

<dialog open id="dialog1">
  <p>Janela de diálogo 1</p>
  <button onclick="this.parentElement.close()">Fechar</button>
</dialog>

<dialog open id="dialog2">
  <p>Janela de diálogo 2</p>
  <button onclick="this.parentElement.close()">Fechar</button>
</dialog>
```

Já utilizando `showModal()`, a janela 1 se sobreporá à 2, porém, perceba que quando uma janela sobrepõem outras, as que são sobrepostas não são fechadas.

> Qual é a compatibilidade dessa tag?

Quase nulo. Para ver o suporte atual, basta acessar o [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=dialog), mas neste exato momento basicamente apenas o Chrome possui suporte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que já abrange a grande maioria dos usuários da Internet, bem como o próprio site aponta, mas pessoalmente eu não recomendo seu uso, por ora.

> Essa tag tem futuro?

A curto prazo, tudo indica que não. Como comentei, algo saiu errado durante a implementação deste elemento e a própria W3C diz que este elemento poderá ser removido. Não fica muito claro se será removido por os navegadores não o implementarem, ou se eles não implementaram devido algum problema de especificação. Porém, este elemento tem todas as características que o HTML 5 propôs, então acredito que, em algum momento do tempo, ele será redefinido ou reimplementado, corrigindo as falhas que o tornou inutilizável no momento.

Até segundas ordens, o ideal é não utilizá-lo em produção se não quiser ter dores de cabeça.

---

Como comentado pelo [Felipe Marinho](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/64560/felipe-marinho), é possível acompanhar a implementação em alguns navegadores:

- [Mozilla Firefox: [meta] Implement the HTML5 dialog element](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=840640)
- [Microsoft Edge: `<dialog>` element for modals](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/dialogelementformodals/)

Comment: Excelente resposta, apesar de não termos mais informações, cita fontes dos *consórcios*, talvez no futuro quando conseguirmos mais detalhes será possivel atualiza-la, mas no momento já esta bem completa.

Comment: Aí sim, uma resposta completa e fácil de entender.

Comment: Caso alguém queira acompanhar o status da implementação do elemento no [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=840640) e no [Edge](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/dialogelementformodals/).

Comment: Legal! Não conhecia essa TAG. Parabéns pela resposta, completa e clara. +1