# Qual a diferença entre usar type submit em buttom e input?

Tags: html, html5, formulário, usabilidade

Eu sempre fiz formulários com `<input type="submit" value="Enviar">`, porém observando a [documentação do bootstrap](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#form-controls) percebi que eles usam Submit, então decidi adotar esse método pois sempre achei estranho o texto "Enviar" dentro do *value* de um *input*.

Queria saber qual é a diferença entre os dois usos.

Imagino que o `<input type="submit" value="Enviar">` seja para o caso de precisar usar dois e assim filtrar no servidor ou por javascript, o qual opção de envio o usuário escolheu. É isso?

Comment: `button`, por padrão, possui `tabindex=0` e, portanto, deve ser acessível através da navegação por `Tab` (ler mais [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/194840/como-e-onde-funciona-o-tabindex)). Se não está assim, você deve ter alterado manualmente.

Comment: tem coisa interessante aqui http://www.criarweb.com/artigos/botoes-html-com-etiqueta-button.html