# Icone no input com bootstrap

Tags: html, css, html5, twitter-bootstrap

Como faço para adicionar um ícone do *bootstrap* no meu `input` desta forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você também pode fazer com que o ícone pareça dentro do `input` posicionando-o sobre ele e adicionando um `padding-left` no `input`, exemplo:

```css
.left-inner-addon {
    position: relative;
}
.left-inner-addon i {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px 12px;
    pointer-events: none;
    color: #666;
}
.left-inner-addon input.form-control {
    padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group left-inner-addon">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ida">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Você pode utilizar a classe `input-group-addon` para fazer o que deseja.

Veja o exemplo baixo:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
      </span>
    <input class="form-control left-border-none" type="text" placeholder="Ida" />
  </div>
</div>


<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputAmount">Amount (in dollars)</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="Amount">
      <div class="input-group-addon">.00</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

[Veja a documentação.](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-basic)

Answer (score 1):

Utilize as classes `input-group` e `input-group-btn` como no exemplo:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
      </button>
    </span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Referência: [documentação bootstrap(em inglês)](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups)

Comment: Só lembrando que o elemento `button` possui, por padrão, `tabindex` igual a 0 e entra na lista de navegação pelo teclado. Neste caso, como será meramente decorativo, é interessante definir `tabindex="-1"` para que o foco seja passado diretamente ao `input`. Leitura complementar: [Como e onde funciona o tabindex?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/194840/5878). Semanticamente, utilizar `input-group-addon`, como especificado na outra resposta, faz mais sentido.